# form onclick create js var to use in jquery function for form name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 4 forms on 1 page, one for each package. Can I use the form's onclick to establish a var and use it in the jquery function? The jquery function is included in a js file assigned to the the page. Just want to access the var in the jquery function for a specific form to be submitted.

```
    <form action="javascript:" method="POST" id="buy-form_2" 
onclick="javascript:$thisform='buy-form_2';" >

    var thisformtext = "#"+$thisform;
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(thisformtext).submit(function(event)
    {
```

i may or may not be close but this one escapes me...

Very curious

Edit: ended up using:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){       

window.buyform = '#'+"buy-form_"+$(this).attr('id').slice(-1);//alert(buyform); 

.......

}
```

I know window.var is overloaded but beats 4 X 12 jquery functions

Thanks for the help!

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to differentiate form, you can have id check.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'buy-form_2'){
        ............
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: trying to re-use a few functions for the forms. but if its not possible, I will write form specific functions. Trying to avoid a giant js file if possible. thanks for the quick reply

Comment: not really clear, what you want to achieve? can you explain little bit more

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Can't rep because I just joined but I'll get you later. I did choose your answer.